# JMS ActiveMQ SpringBoot .FailoverTransport

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

iam trying to connected to remote broker url in activeMQ (activemq installed in unix vm)

iam able to connect from browser from my laptop.

while running springboot iam getting this error

--- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Failed to connect to [tcp://http://199.247.18.11:61616] after: 8 attempt(s) continuing to retry.

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove https:// from your connection string. Port 61616 is expecting JMS connections.

Your connection string should be tcp://199.247.18.11:61616 or something similar. There *is* a rest API that (I think) goes through the built in HTTP server but it's not going to listen on 61616 and it's going to have a much longer URL. Something like

```
http://admin:admin@localhost:8161/api/message?destination=queue://myqueue
```

Comment: not working this is the borker url  activemq: 
  broker-url: failover:(tcp://http://199.247.18.11:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=1000&maxReconnectDelay=60000&warnAfterReconnectAttempts=2
2018-05-01 07:41:51.312  WARN 6560 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Failed to connect to [tcp://http://199.247.18.11:61616] after: 2 attempt(s) continuing to retry.

Comment: it worked after removing http ://                                                                              thanks

Answer (score 0):

still issue 
yml file
activemq: 
  broker-url: failover:(tcp://http://199.247.18.11:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=1000&maxReconnectDelay=60000&warnAfterReconnectAttempts=2

error:
2018-05-01 07:41:51.312  WARN 6560 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Failed to connect to [tcp://http://199.247.18.11:61616] after: 2 attempt(s) continuing to retry.